# Does default isolation level setting in Django depend on database default isolation level?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database, isolation-level

I read [**Isolation level**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#isolation-level) in Django documentation and it says as shown below:

> Like PostgreSQL itself, Django defaults to the READ COMMITTED
> isolation level.

So, if I use **Django** with **MySQL** whose default isolation level is **`REPEATABLE READ`**:

- Is the default isolation level setting in **Django** also **`REPEATABLE READ`**?

Or

- Is the default isolation level setting in **Django** still **`READ COMMITTED`**?

Answer (score 0):

check the source code of django

```
django.db.backends.mysql.base.py
```

Here you will get the line as

```
options = settings_dict['OPTIONS'].copy()
isolation_level = options.pop('isolation_level', 'read committed')
if isolation_level:
    isolation_level = isolation_level.lower()
    if isolation_level not in self.isolation_levels:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured(
            "Invalid transaction isolation level '%s' specified.\n"
            "Use one of %s, or None." % (
                isolation_level,
                ', '.join("'%s'" % s for s in sorted(self.isolation_levels))
            ))
self.isolation_level = isolation_level
```

so you got your answer.